# tabularray + beamer conditional rule display

Tags: beamer, tabularray

I'd like to add a `\toprule` in a `tabularray` only in `presentation` `mode`.

I tried a simple `\mode<beamer>` but I get 2 problems.

1. in `beamerarticle`, there is an extra space in the table
2. in `beamer`, it generates an error.

[image]

[image]

**M(almost)WE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

%\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={lll}}
        Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\ 
            \mode<beamer>{\toprule}
        Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
        Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you define a `\NewTableCommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

%\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\NewTableCommand{\beamertoprule}{\mode<beamer>{\toprule}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={lll}}
        Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\ 
        \beamertoprule 
        Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
        Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Using `article` with `beamerarticle`:

[image]

Using `beamer`:

[image]